# if ng-repeat is for a list of objects what AngularJS directive should I use for a single object?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller that sets a JSON object equal too a $scope.

How do I access it in the view? I have accessed lists and arrays with ng-repeat but what directive should I use to access just a single object? The tutorials I've seen only show results from lists using ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a directive to display a simple object. You use AngularJS expressions: [AngularJS expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Let's say you have an object like this in your **controller:**

```
$scope.obj = {};
$scope.obj.message = 'Hello World';
```

Just display on object like this in your **view:**

```
{{obj.message}}
```

Also, there are many good tutorials out there for AngularJS. I myself followed [Egghead's](https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs) tutorials.

However, if you really want to use a directive with an element, try [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)